# Develop and test React on production server

Tags: reactjs

I have a server with Node.js and React installed (and I am using Nginx). I don't want to develop the React application on my local machine, I need to develop it directly on the server. But whatever change I make, I need to run the build process so I can see the effect on internet in the browser.
Is there a way of how to develop so that all changes take effect right away without need to run build command? I am new to React so I am not yet that much familiar with it.

Comment: you need to automate the process, ie when you do some thing like saving a file or pushing a commit, it triggers the build?

how are you changing the code on server right now ?

Comment: I am using online IDEs like Codetasty or Codeanywhere. So I would either need to run build process on each saving of file or to change somehow the configuration of React so that it does not require build process and the changes take effect right away.

Comment: Or is there a way to use something like "local server" on the ubuntu server but instead of using localhost I would configure the server to use the IP address (domain) and some port?